# Q_EMIT not working from connected slot, only with QTimer slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am trying to emit a signal, which works if the slot if hooked up to a `QTimer`. However if the slot is hooked up to a `QPushButton` for example, it doesn't work. For example, I have a run() function that it connected to a 1 second QTimer. The `run()` function contains `Q_EMIT textChanged("Test")`  This signal works as expected. However, if I have a QPushButton connected to a slot, which also contains `Q_EMIT textChanged("Test")` nothing happens...why is this???

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPushButton>

class Counter : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit Counter(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
      QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
      connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(run()));
      timer->start(1000);

      QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
      QPushButton *OK = new QPushButton("OK");
      connect(OK, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(OKalarmLimits()));
      layout->addWidget(OK);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void textChanged(const QString &text);
   Q_SLOT void run() { Q_EMIT textChanged("Run - Counter"); }
   Q_SLOT void OKalarmLimits() { Q_EMIT textChanged("Button Clicked"); }
};

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QPlainTextEdit *box;
public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
      QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

      box = new QPlainTextEdit();
      box->setMaximumHeight(400);
      box->setMinimumWidth(400);
      layout->addWidget(box);

      QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
      tabWidget->addTab(new Counter(), tr("Counter"));
      layout->addWidget(tabWidget);

      QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
      connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(run()));
      timer->start(1000);
   }
   Q_SLOT void updateWidgets(const QString &t) { box->appendPlainText(t); }
   Q_SLOT void run() { box->appendPlainText("Run - Window"); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow s;
   Counter m;
   s.show();
   s.connect(&m, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SLOT(updateWidgets(QString)));
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Alright I added the minimum self contains example. And no, there are no errors being thrown when my code is run in debug mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's real easy. There are two different counters, and you're connecting to the wrong one.

The `Counter` instance in `main()`, the one that you connect to, is never shown (you don't call its `show()` method after all!). You need to connect to the instance that is created in this line: `tabWidget->addTab(new Counter(), tr("Counter"));`

One solution would be do the connection in `MainWindow()`:

```
 Counter * counter = new Counter();
 QObject::connect(counter, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SLOT(updateWidgets(QString)));

 QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
 tabWidget->addTab(counter, tr("Counter"));
 layout->addWidget(tabWidget,1,0);
```

This also illustrates why minimal examples should really be minimal. Were you to continue working on minimization, you'd have found the bug. Essentially, you can delete the lines below from `main()` without any change in behavior: this would be a dead giveaway that the counter you think of is not the one.

```
Counter m;
QObject::connect(&m, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), &s,SLOT(updateWidgets(QString)));
```